# What is the effective DataFormatString if none is used?

Tags: c#

Using the `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString:="0,0.0")]` attribute, you can set a `DataFormatString` or you can leave it off and it will display with the default data format for that data type.

What is the code to just use the default? In my code I'm formatting everything:

```
Value = Value.ToString(FieldMetaData.Format);
```

I need a default format string for those fields that have no attribute. I want them to behave as if I didn't set the format. I can't leave it an empty string because it simply returns `null` in that case.

Comment: Have you tried an empty string as default? From docs: "The default is an empty string (""), which indicates that no special formatting is applied to the field value."

Comment: @JeanLourenço, yes and the line of code above return null in that case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by only using format if it's a number and setting up default formats for the numeric types I use, like `int` and `decimal`

Answer (score 0):

This is the default date time format, but it also depends on the region.

"yyyyMMdd HH.mm.ss"

I don't know if there is any way to query with from you system, but if there is a way it would probably be in the culture settings. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx